# Drawing lattice and its dual in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have been trying to draw the lattice shown below [image: lattice]
Here is my code

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=1cm,purple,thick] (0,0) grid (4,4);
\draw[step=0.5cm,blue,dashed,thick] (0.5,0.5) grid (3.5,3.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Of course, the code is not giving the diagram above. I can manually insert the filled and empty bullet points, which is time-consuming and not worthy. How to insert these bullet points using any loop command? Also, how to extend the dotted lines at the edges beyond the solid lines and add legends?

It happens mainly that Tex experts post answers, and they code like magicians, which is hard for a novice like me to follow. It would be great if someone gave some references where the fundamentals of their code for a given answer are discussed. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done using `grid` with no loops.

The basics can be found in the Ti*k*Z manual, section 14.8 **The Grid Operation**. The trick with the dots I don't think is in the manual.

- The solid grid requires no options.
- The dashed grid requires a `shift`.
- The solid dots use `line width=3pt, line cap=round, dash pattern=on 0pt off 1cm`.
- The open dots use `double, double distance=2.2pt, line cap=round, dash pattern=on 0pt off 1cm` together with a `shift`.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) grid (5,5);
\draw[densely dashed, shift={(-.5,-.5)}] (.1,.1) grid (5.9,5.9);
\draw[line width=3pt, line cap=round, dash pattern=on 0pt off 1cm](0,0) grid (5,5);
\draw[shift={(-.5,-.5)}, double, double distance=2.2pt, line cap=round, dash pattern=on 0pt off 1cm] (1,1) grid (5,5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The left upper empty dot is missing when I compile your code, any idea why? And the black dots are very irregular, maybe due to the concept of using dash pattern.

Comment: @SebGlav: I don't know. I can't reproduce what you're describing. Maybe something left over in an aux file?